# Clicking checkbox label doesn't work in ajax modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, label, modal-dialog

I have a checkbox formatted like so:

```
<label for="option1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1"> Foo
</label>
```

The checkbox appears in a jQuery modal. When the contents of the modal are pulled from the same page that the modal is activated from then clicking the `<label>` checks the checkbox as expected.

But when the exact same contents of the modal are pulled via Ajax from an external file, clicking the `<label>` no longer checks the checkbox. You have to click directly on the checkbox to check it.

Why does the `<label>` clicking behavior change if the contents are being pulled via Ajax?

(I can provide the JS I'm using to pull the external file if needed, but thought this might be a broader problem/solution perhaps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a live event, as you element appears to DOM at late.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox][id^=option]', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Don't use `delegate()`. It makes you sound like a Dalek. (More seriously: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.")

Comment: Thanks @TheSystemRestart! That got me on the right track. Within the external file I ended up including this:

    `$('label').click(function(){
        $(this).children('input').attr('checked', 'checked');
        setupLabel();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is deeper than simply needing a live event handler, as providing such an event handler didn't fully solve the same problem for me. The jQuery dialog ends up cloning the HTML to create/display the dialog, which duplicates the ids in the clone. Within the click event handler, if I used a simple id selector of the form `$('#'+id)` to find the corresponding input element, it did not find the input element in the dialog. I ended up restricting the selector to the current form I was in, as in `$(this).closest('form').find('#'+id)`, which worked for me. The full handler looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'form label', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("for");
    if (id.length > 0) {
        // Because this is a dialog box, restrict our search to
        // the form we are currently on to avoid finding the same id
        // elsewhere.
        var $checkbox = $(this).closest('form').find('#'+id);
        $checkbox.attr("checked", !$checkbox.attr("checked"));
    }
    return false;
});
```